# Max number of nodes in non-binary tree in summation form

Tags: graph-theory, summation-method

Can some body help me to find total number of nodes in this tree network see the picture [tree network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKD0e.jpg), here Level-1 one has 4 nodes, and the next level has 3 and so 2, 2 is the minimum number of children a parent can have and there are maximum 3 levels allowed. What is the mathematical way of writing this in a summation form. for example the number of nodes in this example is 41 but how such a number is calculated through formula. If the nodes in the levels are not known then what would be its general formula?

[image]

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} n^{\underline{i}} 
\end{eqnarray*}
where $n^{\underline{i}} =n(n-1) \cdots (n-i+1)$ is the fallling factorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be simply described with the following equation:

$N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}}= \sum_{n=1}^{4}{\frac{4!}{(4-n)!}}$

With N-1 being the maximum level of 3. i.e. N=4.

Comment: what is `i` here?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the error, now its `n` instead of `i`, and it runs from 1 to N, or 1 to 4 in this case

Comment: thanks, But if i want to find out the max number of nodes at a particular level then how would i go about it?

Comment: Lets assume you want to know the number of nodes at level L1, i.e. n=1. Then, you evaluate 4!/(4-n)! = 4!/(4-1)! = 4!/3! = 4.

Comment: Thank you I would mark you answer, but can you please also write an alternate way to describe the same thing without summation please?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know any other way of writing that. unless you mean to actually evaluate the sum.

Comment: Actually I am stuck in the problem, and need to calculate the total number of time slots required for  all the nodes in this tree topology, in which each child node requires one slot for transmitting data and each parent node required one`n+1` slots n depends on the number of child nodes. I need the formula in upstream transmission and downstream transmission. I would highly appreciate your response in helping me calculate this.

Answer (score 0):

This post explains how to calculate an estimation of the total number of nodes in the tree, not the exact number.

If n is the number of levels in a similar tree, the number of nodes in the final level is n! (n factorial). The number of nodes in all the levels working backwards is as follows:

- **Level - Total Nodes**
- n - n! (same as saying n!/1!)
- n-1 - n!/2! (total nodes in level n divided by 2)
- n-2 - n!/3! (total nodes in level n divided by 2, then by 3)
- n-3 - n!/4! (total nodes in level n divided by 2, then by 3, then by
  4)
- ...
- root node - n!/n! (equals 1)

If you add up the formulas for total nodes at each level and substitute n!/1! for n! since they are equal, you would get the following formula:

n!/1! + n!/2! + n!/3! + n!/4! + ... + n!/n!

take out the common factor n!

n!(1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + ... + 1/n!)

the stuff in the parentheses is similar to the following formula for the constant e:

e = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + ...

except it's missing the initial number 1, therefore the formula to approximate the total number of nodes in the entire tree is

**n!(e-1)** where n is the number of levels (depth) in the tree.

If you apply this formula to the tree in the original question, there are 4 levels so 4!(e-1) is about 41.2387, and the actual number of nodes is 41.